# How to show image in specific time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have TableViewController and ViewController. In ViewController I save time and in TableViewController I want to show image in table cell if time more then 1:00. But my code doesn’t work… Help me please.

Code in TableViewController

```
_timeElapsed.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"time0"];

if (self.timeElapsed.text  >= @"1:00") {
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28.5, 23, 25, 25)];
    imageView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [imageView2.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    imageView2.tag = 3;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
    UIImageView *imgView2 = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    imgView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory.png"];
}
```

**@seto nugroho**

Now my _timeElapsed.text = 2:57 but image doesn’t show

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];



_timeElapsed.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"time0"];

NSString *stringFromInput = self.timeElapsed.text;
NSString *stringToCompare = @"1:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"m:ss";

NSDate *timeFromInput = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringFromInput];
NSDate *timeToCompare = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringToCompare];

if ([timeFromInput compare:timeToCompare] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    //actual time is greater
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28.5, 23, 25, 25)];
    imageView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [imageView2.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    imageView2.tag = 3;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
    UIImageView *imgView2 = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    imgView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory.png"];
} else {
    //not greater than 1 minutes

}

[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 70, 0, 1)];
return cell;
}
```

**@iOS Geek**

If `timeString = @"0:05"` and `if (timeInSeconds > 1)` image doesn’t show but in this case I see image.

```
NSString *timeString = @"0:05";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"mm:ss";
NSDate *timeDate = [formatter dateFromString:timeString];

formatter.dateFormat = @"mm";
int minutes = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];
formatter.dateFormat = @"ss";
int seconds = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];

int timeInSeconds = seconds + minutes * 60;

if (timeInSeconds > 1) {
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28.5, 23, 25, 25)];
    imageView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [imageView2.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    imageView2.tag = 3;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
    UIImageView *imgView2 = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    imgView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory.png"];
}
```

Comment: is there any image named "accessory.png" in your main bundle? have you register your custom table view cell class? there are a lot of thing that make your image doesn't show. Have you try debugging your code?

Comment: If I take away `if ([timeFromInput compare:timeToCompare] == NSOrderedDescending)` the image will be displayed.

Comment: what is the value of `self.timeElapsed.text`?

Comment: Now my _timeElapsed.text = 2:57 but image doesn’t show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compare string values, unless you want to see if they are equal character by character(in which case you use "isEqualToString:"). 
Convert you time to integer values and then compare.

**Update**

You can use NSDateFormatter to get seconds and minutes from the time string:

```
NSString *timeString = @"3:31";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"mm:ss";
NSDate *timeDate = [formatter dateFromString:timeString];

formatter.dateFormat = @"mm";
int minutes = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];
formatter.dateFormat = @"ss";
int seconds = [[formatter stringFromDate:timeDate] intValue];

int timeInSeconds = seconds + minutes * 60;
```

Comment: How to convert my time to integer values and then compare?

Comment: @User : I have updated my answer. You can use this to convert your string value to integer value, and then compare.

Comment: @User -  since the value you have is in seconds, you should use : if (timeInSeconds > 60) { //your image code }

Answer (score 0):

It's bad to compare time like this:

```
self.timeElapsed.text  >= @"1:00"
```

Please convert it to `NSDate` or `Int`(not so good but easy). Like this:

```
[[self.timeElapsed.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] firstObject].intValue > 1
```

Comment: BTW, it's bad to create and add UIImageView in your table view data source! Please check if there is already one added to at least.

Comment: `Int(self.timeElapsed.text.componentsSeparatedByString(":").first!) > 1`
 it is objective-c?

Comment: Oh, sorry.I will change it to oc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you are comparing String, which obviously is not what you want.
You should convert your string to date and then compare it.

```
NSString *stringFromInput = self.timeElapsed.text;
NSString *stringToCompare = @"1:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"m:ss";

NSDate *timeFromInput = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringFromInput];
NSDate *timeToCompare = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringToCompare];

if ([timeFromInput compare:timeToCompare] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    //actual time is greater
} else {
    //not greater than 1 minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn warnings on. The compiler will warn you that you are comparing pointers with the >= operator, which is often undefined behaviour, and often nonsense, as in your case.

```
self.timeElapsed.text  >= @"1:00"
```

compares two pointers. It compares a pointer to the location where the object self.timeElapsed.text is stored, and a pointer to the location where the object @"1:00" is stored. Which is obviously nonsense and completely unrelated to the actual values of the objects.

Comment: Could you give a solution to my problem in code? Nothing works as I have not tried